# Is it necessary to integrate the SKAdNetwork into the own app on iOS 14 when Branch links are used for ad campaigns?

Tags: branch.io

According to this [guide](https://branch.io/ios-14/) it is recommended to [integrate the SKAdNetwork into the own app](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/branchskadnetwork-integration-instructions), so that iOS paid ads attribution can be performed. But the [ad network list](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/ad-networks-supporting-skadnetwork) states that all the listed companies do "not send postbacks to Branch yet". So actually, I have multiple questions:

1. What is ment by the word "postback" here? Does this include app install attributions? If so, integrating the SKAdNetwork wouldn't have any effect.
2. Is it necessary to integrate the SKAdNetwork into the own app on iOS 14 when Branch links are used for ad campaigns (e. g. Facebook) and the basic Branch integration was performed for the own app?

Answer (score 1):

1. From Branch's [documentation](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/ad-networks-supporting-skadnetwork)

> SKAdNetwork - Does not send postbacks to Branch yet

To get app install attribution data for iOS 14 devices that have opted-out of IDFA tracking, Apple has told the Ad Networks (e.g., Facebook, Tapjoy) to integrate with SkAdNetwork. The Ad Networks will get the install attribution data in a postback directly from the user's device. Branch (and other MMPs) have no way to access this install attribution data (postback), unless the Ad Network sends it to them.

2. Most Ad Networks will provide you with an SDK that does the SkAdNetwork integration work for you. All you'll have to do is update the app's Info.plist to include the ID's for the Ad Networks you use.

Answer (score 0):

Postbacks constitute of payload for the attributed conversion data that would be sent to the configured server endpoint.

Would request you to check on our Branch documentation below which would clarify on your queries for the SkAd network integration : https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/branchskadnetwork-integration-instructions

Comment: So, in conclusion, it is necessary to perform the Branch SKAdNetwork mobile integration to receive the ad attribution data from Apple, because the ad networks do not forward this data to Branch?